# Tag Synonym Request: [monitor-resolution] -> [resolution]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Seems like [monitor-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/monitor-resolution) should be synomized with [resolution.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion; I've added a synonym.