# Tag synonym request: [screen-resolution] -> [resolution]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

We have separate [resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution) and [screen-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution) tags. [resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution) is almost always used, and [screen-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution) almost never. Theoretically these are different, as resolution applies to things besides screens ...but practically speaking these tags are probably extremely unlikely to be used differently, especially considering that:

- All the [resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution) seem to be about screen resolution.
- [monitor-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/monitor-resolution) [is a synonym](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1753/tag-synonym-request-monitor-resolution-resolution) targeting [resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution). [screen-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution) should almost certainly be considered to mean the same thing as [monitor-resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/monitor-resolution), and thus should also be a synonym of [resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/resolution).